# Why is my antlr4 grammar not parsing this text correctly

Tags: antlr4

I have the following grammar in antlr4 that I am using to parse betting lines.

```
grammar betting;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

market
    :   zero
    |   array
    |   grid
    ;

zero
    :   (outcomePrice NEWLINE)+ outcomePrice
    ;
    
array
    :  TEXT NEWLINE list NEWLINE TEXT list NEWLINE TEXT list
    ;

grid
    :   (TEXT NEWLINE (linePrice NEWLINE)+)+
    ;

list
    :   (NEWLINE NUMBER)+
    ;
    
outcomePrice
    :   TEXT NEWLINE NUMBER
    ;
    
linePrice
    :   line NEWLINE NUMBER
    |   SCORE NEWLINE NUMBER
    ;
    
line
    :   SINGLE_LINE
    |   SPLIT_LINE
    ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
 
fragment DIGIT 
    :   [0-9]
    ;
    
fragment CHARACTER
    :   [ \u00a0\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-0-9]
    ;

SPLIT_LINE
    :   SINGLE_LINE ',' SINGLE_LINE
    ;
    
SINGLE_LINE
    :   [+\-] NUMBER
    ;
    
SCORE
    :   DIGIT+ '-' DIGIT+
    ;
    
NUMBER         
    :   DIGIT+ (.DIGIT+)? 
    ;
    
TEXT
    :   CHARACTER+
    ;
    
NEWLINE
    :   '\n'
    ;
    
WS
    :   [ \t\r]+ -> skip
    ;
```

I am testing against the following text,

```
Kodagu FC
-1.0,-1.5
1.575
-1.5
1.725
-1.5,-2.0
1.925
-2
2.050
-2.0,-2.5
2.300
Rebels FC
+1.0,+1.5
2.250
+1.5
1.975
+1.5,+2.0
1.875
+2
1.675
+2.0,+2.5
1.550
```

For some reason suddenly a number is not being recognised, I expect the pattern to continue and the 'line' to break/exit at the '\n' character. Why is this the case and are there any tools to easily discover this?

[image]

Comment: The lexer rules of your grammar have several overlapping string recognition. For example, a space `' '` is recognized as both `TEXT` and `WS`; `'123'` is recognized as both `NUMBER` and `TEXT`. You should not be writing lexer rules that overlap in matching. Antlr lexers are not guided or influenced whatsoever by the parser. In fact, for small inputs, the input is completely read and tokenized before the parser really gets going. lab.antlr.org does not show the token types. Unfortunately, the Antlr Tool TestRig also does not. Write a driver and print out the token types.

Comment: @kaby76 The test rig does print the token types if you call it with the `-tokens` option. You can also run it with `tokens` in place of the non-terminal name (`grun -tokens tokens`) to only run the lexer and not invoke the parser at all.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks, I was only looking at the drawing. Didn't know that.

Comment: @kaby76 Does order not manage the overlapping condition of number and text, that which is not a number is text? And that which is both a number and text is a number. Any suggestions to handle ambiguities better?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to overlap lexer rules, and done in more grammars. But, it's best to print out the tokens when the parse doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:   DIGIT+ (.DIGIT+)?
```

`.` means "any character". The above pattern matches either a sequence of digits or two sequences of digits with *any character* in between. So this will match "12.34", but it can also match "12,34" or, yes, "12\n34".

Put the dot inside quotes so it only matches literal dots.